# Rails paperclip S3 attachment not deleted (bad request)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm developing a rails API. I use the `paperclip` gem to store images in Amazon S3. I'm just using my own access key for the bucket, without any added policies. The attachments are correctly uploaded and stored in S3, but when I destroy a record, the attachments are not deleted. I also tried deleting the attachment alone, and that gave the following error:

```
[AWS S3 400 0.382023 0 retries] head_object(:bucket_name=>"my-bucket-name",:key=>"the/url/to/the/image.jpg") AWS::S3::Errors::BadRequest AWS::S3::Errors::BadRequest
```

In my model:

```
has_attached_file :main_image
validates_attachment :main_image, presence: true,
                     content_type: { content_type: %w(image/jpeg image/png)},
                     size: { in: 0 .. 1.megabytes }
```

In my configuration:

```
# Paperclip config
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_credentials: {
        bucket: ENV.fetch('AWS_S3_BUCKET'),
        access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_S3_REGION'),
    }
}
```

The app is running on Heroku. Is this a permissions issue? Note that I'm using the `aws-sdk` gem version 1.66.

Answer (score 0):

This is a permissions issue with AWS S3 since you are able to upload but not delete. Did you create an AWS IAM user to generate an Access Key and Secret Key? If so can you paste your policy?

Comment: I did not create an IAM user yet, so I'm just using the root access key.

Comment: why? I created AWS IAM user to generate an Access Key and Secret Key? does this effect? i cant delete the images